# Why does std::format and std::vformat take forwarding references for its arguments?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdformat

I needed to use `std::format` in a context like this at work:

```cpp
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < ...; ++i)
{
   std::format("some string {}", i);
}
```

and since the cycle variable `i` is passed as a forwarding reference, the automated linter gave a warning that it's passed by reference and could potentially be modified.

After reading through cppreference and the [std::format proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0645r10.html#formatter.requirements) it seems that the `Formatter` requirement allows the formatted argument to be non-const, but I couldn't figure out why, and the draft actually suggests `const Args&...` parametrization instead of `Args&&...`

As an experiment I tried moving a string, or even specializing `std::formatter`for my own type:

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct MyStruct {
    std::string a = "abc";

    MyStruct(){}
    MyStruct(const MyStruct&) { std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl; }
    MyStruct(MyStruct&&) noexcept { std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl; }
    MyStruct& operator=(const MyStruct&) { std::cout << "copy assignment" << std::endl; return *this; }
    MyStruct& operator=(MyStruct&&) noexcept { std::cout << "move assignment" << std::endl; return *this; }
};

template <typename CharT>
struct std::formatter<MyStruct, CharT> : std::formatter<std::string, CharT> {
    template<typename FormatContext>
    auto format(MyStruct id, FormatContext& ctx) const {
        return std::formatter<std::string, CharT>::format(id.a, ctx);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string a = std::format("formatted {}", MyStruct{});
    return 0;
}
```

But even when declaring `format` with an `lvalue` parameter instead of a const&, only copy ctor gets called (`std::vformat` with `std::make_format_args(MyStruct{})` results in the same).

So the final question is, why does `std::format` take forwarding reference arguments, why not restrict them to `const&`?

Comment: If you need to make the linter happy, you could pass `std::as_const(i)` instead (which it hopefully understands to not modify its own parameter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[P2418](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2418r2.html) added support for formatters that can mutate the value being formatted. As the paper explains, the original motivation was for `std::generator` and similar types. Note, however, that forwarding references are present only on the entry points where arguments are first passed into the formatting API (`std::format`, `std::vformat`, etc); the more internal machinery (such as `std::basic_format_arg`) only deals with lvalue references, which may be to either a `const` or non-`const` type.